# How do I set the option value of a dropdown list populated by a SQL table in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdown list which is populated by a SQL table, it populates fine, however when writing to a SQL table, the options are replaced by letters and numbers separated by -. For example:

31d-t623-sv7s-23cd-b2jk-f5271kd52

I think this is because the value of the options is not being set when populating the list. How do I go about doing this?

```
<select asp-for="LoadTable.Team" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="team" title="Select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Teams, "Id", "Team"))">
```

Comment: Please correct tag and save others' time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to the following worked

```
<select asp-for="LoadTable.Team" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="team" title="Select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Teams, "Team", "Team"))">
```